# Show/Hide H4's isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue trying to show/hide some `h4`s. The goal is to click an information `li` link and show the corresponding `h4`'s text in the next `table` over (one at a time), but this is not working.

I have tried using `.css("display","none/block")`, `.style("display","none/block")`, and a few others in my JQuery.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zZ7Rt/1/)**

The `li` links code

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <th><h2>Quick Facts</h2></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <th>
             <ul style="font-size:15px">
                 <li id="_Join"><a href="#">How to join</a></li>
                 <li id="_Who"><a href="#">Who we are</a></li>
                 <li id="_Officers"><a href="#">Officers</a></li>
                 <li id="_Other1"><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                 <li id="_Other2"><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                 <li id="_Other3"><a href="#">Other</a></li>
             </ul>
         </th>
      </tr>
</table>
```

The `h4` text I want to display

```
<table style="word-wrap: break-word">
   <tr>
      <th>
         <h4 class="informational" id="Join">How to join</h4>
         <h4 class="informational" id="Who">Who</h4>
         <h4 class="informational" id="Officers">Officers</h4>
         <h4 class="informational" id="Other1">Other1</h4>
         <h4 class="informational" id="Other2">Other2</h4>
         <h4 class="informational" id="Other3">Other3</h4>
      </th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.informational').hide();
});

$('[id^=_]').click(function () {
    $('.informational').hide();
    var naming = $(this).attr('id').replace('_', '');
    alert("selected ID is: " + naming); 
    document.getElementById(naming).show();
});
```

Any help appreciated!

P.S. If there is a better way of doing this please let me know. Thanks!

*Using Bootstrap 3 / MVC 5*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `document.getElementById(naming).show();` with `$('#'+naming).show();`.

`.show()` is a jQuery function and you're attempting to use it on a DOM node.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zZ7Rt/2/)**

Comment: Wow...interesting. You mind giving me a quick explanation (or pointing me to a link) on the difference of starting a JQuery using `$(something).function` vs `document.something.function`. Up until now I didn't know there was a difference...

Comment: Well for starters, you can only use jQuery functions on jQuery objects.

Comment: A jquery object includes the dom object. You can access it doing $(myObject)[0]. Obviously, classic javascript do not know about jQuery.

Comment: Oh...maybe I am miss understanding something then. What exactly defines a document and JQuery object? Isn't `h4` also part of the actual DOM? Sorry if this is bothersome. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, replace `document.getElementById(naming).show();` with `document.getElementById("naming").style.display = "none";`